# Unignoring a file in .gitignore is not working. I want GIT to unignore bin directory?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, microfocus

I have tried the following solution but `.gitignore` overriding the unignore line.

```
!/bin/
```

after compilation, it overrides as follows

```
!/bin/
/bin/
```

Comment: git alone will not change the content of your `.gitignore` file. Try to isolate the step that edits your file

Comment: I'm curious as to what you mean by "after compilation". Git does not have a compilation step, and a `.gitignore` file does not get compiled by any compiler I know of.

Comment: I meant after compiling a program on microfocus the .gitignore file is updated with /bin/

Comment: @veeravenkatarameshchode exactly, hence my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found these settings on microfocus Enterprise Developer :

Windows -> Preferences -> Team - Git -> Projects -> "Automatically ignore derived resources by adding them to .gitignore"

After removing or unchecking the line, it stopped updating /bin/ line on gitignore

Answer (score 1):

If the [microfocus compiler](https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx51/cycomp.htm) is somehow changing the main `.gitignore`, see if adding a `.gitignore` in `bin/` itself would help, with the content

```
!./
```

The alternative would be to wrap the compiler call with a script which would:

- save the `.gitignore` content
- call the compiler
- then restore the `.gitignore` content.

Comment: Found these settings on microfocus Enterprise Developer :  

 Windows -> Preferences -> Team - Git -> Projects -> "Automatically ignore derived resources by adding them to .gitignore"

After removing or uncheck the line, it stopped updating /bin/ line on gitignore